# Creating Swing Tree from Array list

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtree

I have a Array list with two columns one column has child and one has parent e.g

```
label                     Parent

Test
something 1               Test
Something 2               Test
Something 3               Something 1
Something 4               Something 1
Something 5               Something 1
Something 6               Something 5
```

Below is the code I am using to create a tree:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeList.get(0).label);
findChild(root, nodeList);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container content = frame.getContentPane();
final JTree tree = new JTree(root);

static void findChild(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, List<Node> nodeList2) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.size(); i++) {
        if (nodeList2.get(i).parent != null && nodeList2.get(i).parent.equals(parent.toString())) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeList2.get(i).label);
            Parent.add(child);
            findChild(child, nodeList2); // child of child
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is I am having just Test displayed as a root node nothing else below it.
Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class TreeTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
    nodeList.add(new Node("Test"));
    //typo? nodeList.add(new Node("something 1", "Test"));
    nodeList.add(new Node("Something 1", "Test"));
    nodeList.add(new Node("Something 2", "Test"));
    nodeList.add(new Node("Something 3", "Something 1"));
    nodeList.add(new Node("Something 4", "Something 1"));
    nodeList.add(new Node("Something 5", "Something 1"));
    nodeList.add(new Node("Something 6", "Something 5"));

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeList.get(0).label);
    findChild(root, nodeList);
    JTree tree = new JTree(root);
    return new JScrollPane(tree);
  }
  private static void findChild(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, List<Node> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (list.get(i).parent != null && list.get(i).parent.equals(parent.toString())) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(list.get(i).label);
        parent.add(child);
        findChild(child, list); // child of child
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new TreeTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class Node {
  public final String label;
  public final String parent;
  public Node(String label) {
    this(label, null);
  }
  public Node(String label, String parent) {
    this.label = label;
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```